# about an example of operator overloading

Tags: c++

Here are an example of operator overloading from C++ programming language:

```
struct X{
     int I;
     X(int);
     X operator+(int);
};

struct Y{
    int I;
    Y(X);
    Y operator+(X);
    operator  int();
}
```

I am not clear about what does "int I" do in the definitions of both X and Y. Besides, I do not understand how to analyze the functionality of "operator int()" in the definition of X.

Comment: The bodies of the member functions haven't been defined, so these classes don't *do* anything yet...

Answer (score 2):

`operator int()` provides a conversion to `int` from the structure, so you can write:

```
X(4);
Y y(x);
int a = y; // calls Y::operator int()
```

The exact *meaning* of that conversion depends on how the operator is implemented

the `int I` in the structures declare member variables, (both) named `I` and of type `int`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the `int I` in both structs represent the internal state of the objects.

```
Y operator+(X);
```

This is an operator that for `y + x` returns a new object of type `Y`.

```
operator  int();
```

This is a conversion operator, which means that an `Y` can be converted to an `int`.

There is no definition for the operators, so their actual semantics are unknown.